Mercedes-Benz 2008 C350. Turning the steering wheel left or right is stuck
Mercedes-Benz
2008
C350
The vehicle moves forward and backwards no problem. When trying to turn left or right turn it is very very hard.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does it turn at all? Or is it just hard to turn?

Is your power steering pump low on fluid, leaking? Drive belt loose, missing?
